# combining objects with the same properties

Tags: javascript, dynamic-arrays

I have an array of object,

```
let arrPeople = [
                {name: "Jack", expenseType: "food", amount: 50},
                {name: "Kate", expenseType: "food", amount: 60},
                {name: "Rob", expenseType: "transportation", amount: 15},
                {name: "Jack", expenseType: "food", amount: 40},
                {name: "Kate", expenseType: "transportation", amount: 20},
                {name: "Jack", expenseType: "miscellaneous", amount: 30},
                {name: "Rob", expenseType: "transportation", amount: 15}
                ]
```

I want to combine objects that has the same name and expenseType  and add the amounts and retain the other objects that has no similarities.

Expected output:

```
let newArr = [
            {name: "Jack", expenseType: "food", amount: 90},
            {name: "Kate", expenseType: "food", amount: 60},
            {name: "Rob", expenseType: "transportation", amount: 30},
            {name: "Kate", expenseType: "transportation", amount: 20},
            {name: "Jack", expenseType: "miscellaneous", amount: 30}
            ]
```

Please send help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the question is marked as duplicate but I found the requirement in this question is slightly different.

Here is how you can achieve it with nested loop.

Iterate the array and take the first object for example this object

`{name: "Jack", expenseType: "food", amount: 50},`. Now run a second loop and from the array find all the objects which have same `name` and same `expenseType`. If name and expenseType are equal then add the `amount` from other objects to the first object.

Following that set the index of those objects where `name` and `expenseType` matches to `undefined`.

The purpose of doing this is to next time call same `doReduce` function with new array & not to include the object with same `name` and `expenseType` in iteration.

For example `arrPeople` have two object with same `name` and `expenseType`. So we can create a single object with same name and expenseType and add their different `amount` and set index of these two object to undefined.

So it will be like

```
let arrPeople = [undefined, {
    name: "Kate",
    expenseType: "food",
    amount: 60
  },
  {
    name: "Rob",
    expenseType: "transportation",
    amount: 15
  },
  undefined,
  {
    name: "Kate",
    expenseType: "transportation",
    amount: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Jack",
    expenseType: "miscellaneous",
    amount: 30
  },
  {
    name: "Rob",
    expenseType: "transportation",
    amount: 15
  }
]
`
```

No again I was calling doReduce function with a new array by removing the duplicate.

Working example

```js
let arrPeople = [{
    name: 'Jack',
    expenseType: 'food',
    amount: 50
  },
  {
    name: 'Kate',
    expenseType: 'food',
    amount: 60
  },
  {
    name: 'Rob',
    expenseType: 'transportation',
    amount: 15
  },
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    expenseType: 'food',
    amount: 40
  },
  {
    name: 'Kate',
    expenseType: 'transportation',
    amount: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    expenseType: 'miscellaneous',
    amount: 30
  },
  {
    name: 'Rob',
    expenseType: 'transportation',
    amount: 15
  }
];
//
function doReduce(arr, finalArr) {
  // iterate through entire length of the array;
  // take first element of the array and find same object from the arry which have same name and same expense type 
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      // if the expense type and name matches then the amount can be added to the first object of the array
      if (arr[i].name === arr[j].name && arr[i].expenseType === arr[j].expenseType) {
        arr[i].amount += arr[j].amount;
        // setting undefined
        arr[j] = undefined
      }
    }
    finalArr.push(arr[i]);
    arr[i] = undefined;
    // remove all undefined from the array
    const newArr = arr.filter(item => item !== undefined);
    // get all object which are not undefined and call recall doReduce with new array set
    if (newArr.length > 0) {
      return doReduce(newArr, finalArr)
    } else {
      return finalArr
    }
  }
}
console.log(doReduce(arrPeople, []));
```

Slightly compressed code

```js
let arrPeople = [{
    name: 'Jack',
    expenseType: 'food',
    amount: 50
  },
  {
    name: 'Kate',
    expenseType: 'food',
    amount: 60
  },
  {
    name: 'Rob',
    expenseType: 'transportation',
    amount: 15
  },
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    expenseType: 'food',
    amount: 40
  },
  {
    name: 'Kate',
    expenseType: 'transportation',
    amount: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    expenseType: 'miscellaneous',
    amount: 30
  },
  {
    name: 'Rob',
    expenseType: 'transportation',
    amount: 15
  }
];

function doReduce(arr, finalVal) {
  // Note unlike other code, not adding i++, since it is never used
  for (; 0 < arr.length;) {
    for (let b = 1; b < arr.length; b++) {
      arr[0].name === arr[b].name && arr[0].expenseType === arr[b].expenseType && (arr[0].amount += arr[b].amount, arr[b] = void 0);
    }
    finalVal.push(arr[0]);
    arr[0] = void 0;
    b = arr.filter(function(d) {
      return void 0 !== d;
    });
    return 0 < b.length ? doReduce(b, finalVal) : finalVal;
  }
}
console.log(doReduce(arrPeople, []));
```